# Hibernate Table or view does not exist Oracle

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I Have a problem executing an hibernate query on Oracle:

my persistence.xml:

```
<description>ProfileEntityManager</description>
<class>com.entity.User</class>  
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:9999/db"/> 
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/> 
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/> 
    <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
</properties>
```

my entity class com.entity.User:

```
package com.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name ="USER", schema = "SCHEMA")
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
}
```

my java class:

```
        //System.out.println(uid);
        List<User> lp = null;
        try {
            lp = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT iu FROM User iu WHERE iu.userId = ?", User.class)
                    .setParameter(1, uid).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            writeLog(fw, e.getMessage());
        }
```

but when i execute my code, i obtain:

```
Hibernate: SELECT iu FROM User iu WHERE iu.userId = ?
gen 29, 2021 6:36:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000
gen 29, 2021 6:36:59 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00942: tabella o vista inesistente

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Can you help me to find the error?

NOTE: if a use a PreparedStatement with the same connections and query i don't have any issue, so it is not a problem of permissions

Comment: `SELECT iu FROM User iu`??? do you have a column name `iu`? You should use `SELECT * FROM User iu`

Comment: it is the same, also using SELECT *. I have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use `HQL` query with `EntityManager.createNativeQuery` method. This is a mistake.

Try to correct your query in this way:

```java
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.USER WHERE USER_ID = :usrid", User.class)
.setParameter("usrid", uid)
.getResultList();
```

If you use the `SCHEMA` for all your entities, you can put it to the hibernate config:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="SCHEMA"/>
```

then correct your entity definition in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name ="USER")
public class User {
   // ...
}
```

and then correct your query:

```java
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM {h-schema}USER WHERE USER_ID = :usrid", User.class)
.setParameter("usrid", uid)
.getResultList();
```

P.S. And by the way, I would suggest you to correct your hibernate dialect definition. You should use as specific dialect as possible. For example if you use Oracle 10g, you should use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`. You can still use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect` but some new features defined in `Oracle10gDialect` will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add this line to your configuration file

**either**

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

**or**

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

Comment: Mmm I don't know this property, but searching online it seems that enable me to create or update a schema. The table User already exists, can you explain? Thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha